# efficiently growing a dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

On an iterative basis, I'm generating a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
              RIC RICRoot ISIN ExpirationDate                      Exchange           ...            OpenInterest  BlockVolume  TotalVolume2  SecurityDescription  SecurityLongDescription
closingDate                                                                           ...                                                                                                 
2018-03-15   SPH0      SP          2020-03-20  CME:Index and Options Market           ...                     NaN         None          None       SP500 IDX MAR0                     None
2018-03-16   SPH0      SP          2020-03-20  CME:Index and Options Market           ...                     NaN         None          None       SP500 IDX MAR0                     None
2018-03-19   SPH0      SP          2020-03-20  CME:Index and Options Market           ...                     NaN         None          None       SP500 IDX MAR0                     None
2018-03-20   SPH0      SP          2020-03-20  CME:Index and Options Market           ...                     NaN         None          None       SP500 IDX MAR0                     None
2018-03-21   SPH0      SP          2020-03-20  CME:Index and Options Market           ...                     NaN         None          None       SP500 IDX MAR0                     None
```

I turn this into a multi-indexed DF:

```
tmp.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays( [ [contract]*len(tmp.columns), tmp.columns.tolist() ] )
```

Where `contract` is just the reference name for that data, which you can see in the output below as `SPH0`:

```
    SPH0                                                                     ...                                                                                            
              RIC RICRoot ISIN ExpirationDate                      Exchange           ...           OpenInterest BlockVolume TotalVolume2 SecurityDescription SecurityLongDescription
closingDate                                                                           ...                                                                                            
2018-03-15   SPH0      SP          2020-03-20  CME:Index and Options Market           ...                    NaN        None         None      SP500 IDX MAR0                    None
2018-03-16   SPH0      SP          2020-03-20  CME:Index and Options Market           ...                    NaN        None         None      SP500 IDX MAR0                    None
2018-03-19   SPH0      SP          2020-03-20  CME:Index and Options Market           ...                    NaN        None         None      SP500 IDX MAR0                    None
2018-03-20   SPH0      SP          2020-03-20  CME:Index and Options Market           ...                    NaN        None         None      SP500 IDX MAR0                    None
2018-03-21   SPH0      SP          2020-03-20  CME:Index and Options Market           ...                    NaN        None         None      SP500 IDX MAR0                    None
```

I currently have a very inefficient way of merging these DataFrames:

```
if df is None:
            df = tmp;
        else:
            df = df.merge( tmp, how='outer', left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

This is incredibly slow. I want to store all of these tempdf's in an associated mapping style with their respective contract name, and be able to reference their data easily and in a vectorized manner.  What is the optimal solution? Does growing horizontally/vertically matter?

Comment: Why don't you just use `set_index()`?

Comment: When merging? I'm not sure how I could use set_index() to append DataFrame objects to one another.

Comment: Please post full code block with [MCVE] that we can run in our empty Python environments. Is that last piece run inside a `for` loop?

Comment: Could you include your desired output in your post as well?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can just use `pd.concat()` and pass your list of dataframes and the keys for you resulting MultiIndex dataframe. Take the following dataframe samples:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame([                                                                                            
['2018-03-11',   'SPH0',      'SP',          '2020-03-20',  'CME:Index and Options Market'],
['2018-03-12',   'SPH0',      'SP',          '2020-03-20',  'CME:Index and Options Market'],
['2018-03-15',   'SPH0',      'SP',          '2020-03-20',  'CME:Index and Options Market'],
['2018-03-23',   'SPH0',      'SP',          '2020-03-20',  'CME:Index and Options Market'],
['2018-03-24',   'SPH0',      'SP',          '2020-03-20',  'CME:Index and Options Market']],
columns=['closingDate', 'RIC', 'RICRoot', 'ExpirationDate', 'Exchange'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame([                                                                                            
['2018-03-15',   'HAB3',      'HA',          '2020-03-20',  'CME:Index and Options Market'],
['2018-03-16',   'HAB3',      'HA',          '2020-03-20',  'CME:Index and Options Market'],
['2018-03-22',   'HAB3',      'HA',          '2020-03-20',  'CME:Index and Options Market'],
['2018-03-24',   'HAB3',      'HA',          '2020-03-20',  'CME:Index and Options Market'],
['2018-03-20',   'HAB3',      'HA',          '2020-03-20',  'CME:Index and Options Market']],
columns=['closingDate', 'RIC', 'RICRoot', 'ExpirationDate', 'Exchange'])

df3 = pd.DataFrame([                                                                                            
['2018-03-15',   'UHA6',      'UH',          '2020-03-20',  'CME:Index and Options Market'],
['2018-03-16',   'UHA6',      'UH',          '2020-03-20',  'CME:Index and Options Market'],
['2018-03-18',   'UHA6',      'UH',          '2020-03-20',  'CME:Index and Options Market'],
['2018-03-20',   'UHA6',      'UH',          '2020-03-20',  'CME:Index and Options Market'],
['2018-03-21',   'UHA6',      'UH',          '2020-03-20',  'CME:Index and Options Market']],
columns=['closingDate', 'RIC', 'RICRoot', 'ExpirationDate', 'Exchange'])
```

Now call `pd.concat()`:

```
pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], keys=['SPH0','HAB3','UHA6'])
```

Yields:

```
       closingDate              ...                                   Exchange
SPH0 0  2018-03-11              ...               CME:Index and Options Market
     1  2018-03-12              ...               CME:Index and Options Market
     2  2018-03-15              ...               CME:Index and Options Market
     3  2018-03-23              ...               CME:Index and Options Market
     4  2018-03-24              ...               CME:Index and Options Market
HAB3 0  2018-03-15              ...               CME:Index and Options Market
     1  2018-03-16              ...               CME:Index and Options Market
     2  2018-03-22              ...               CME:Index and Options Market
     3  2018-03-24              ...               CME:Index and Options Market
     4  2018-03-20              ...               CME:Index and Options Market
UHA6 0  2018-03-15              ...               CME:Index and Options Market
     1  2018-03-16              ...               CME:Index and Options Market
     2  2018-03-18              ...               CME:Index and Options Market
     3  2018-03-20              ...               CME:Index and Options Market
     4  2018-03-21              ...               CME:Index and Options Market
```

You can also use a list comprehension to create a list of dataframes to pass to `pd.concat()`, for example:

```
my_keys = ['SPH0','HAB3','UHA6']
dfs = [create_df(key) for key in my_keys]
pd.concat(dfs, keys=my_keys)
```

Where the function `create_df()` returns a dataframe.